# Lightweight Component over Heavyweight Component problem

Tags: java, swing, awt

The code pretty huge and involves a lot of different class/methods:

But here is the gist:

There is a main frame : A_Main
Selecting something in the main frame A: opens a JDialog B_Dialog
This B_Dialog has a JPanel on it: C_Panel

This C_Panel comprises of a textfield and a button

On clicking on the textfield/button: opens a tooltip and another JPanel: D_Panel

Now, the problem is:

1) The tooltip overflows the size of B_Dialog and therefore gets truncated

2) D_Panel however; even if its outside the boundary of B_Dialog gets displayed fully

2.1) There are some texfields and drop down menus in this D_Panel

2.2) The mouse events function correctly in this D_Panel items (drop down menus)

2.3) But Keyboard events do not function correct (Textfield)

I would be glad if you could help!

Thanks!

Comment: As "any popup components (`JComboBox`, `JPopupMenu`, `JMenuBar`) created within a modal dialog will be forced to be lightweight, an http://sscce.org/ that shows how you pop up the `JPanel` may be informative. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when I try to enter something in the JAR `JPanel`'s text field, I am not able to do so as this pops out of the border of the main `JDialog` that contains it.

Add a `JScrollPane` around the `JPanel`, and allow it to expand both horizontally and vertically. If this doesn't work, you may need a customized Layout Manager, or use one of the default ones like `GridBagLayout`.

Also, you'll need to gain focus before you can enter text, but that doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Comment: The component is visible over the other component; as in it is not cut at the edges. I am not able to keyboard key the component on top but it is mouse editable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if your JPanel is of the same color, you won't be able to tell where it is unless you add a JScrollPane. Would you mind providing some code? It's hard to guess.

Comment: I have edited the question for better clarity. Please take a look at the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done in newer versions of the JDK.

See, [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/).

Comment: The component is visible over the other component; as in it is not cut at the edges. I am not able to keyboard key the component on top but it is mouse editable